# How to create a local secure wiki?

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

For our office we would love to create a wiki that has pages that stores lots of information on different topics relevant to how we do things (best practice and methodologies etc) that new joiner could access in order to hit the ground running.

This would have to be set up locally on our shared server resource.  Is there a free resource that anyone in the office could contribute to i.e. start a new branch and write up a topic for the rest of the team to use (so would need to be fairly code free)?

Comment: You've already tagged your question [[tag:mediawiki]], what else do you need to know?

Comment: It gives the answer: it should be an answer.

Comment: This is off-topic. Per the official close reason: _It's seeking recommendations for books, software libraries, or other off-site resources. This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers._